# How to create a subscriptable custom type for Python type annotations?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to write a converter for *attrib* that converts a *IterableA* of *Type1* to an *IterableB* or *Type2*.

For example:

```py
converter = make_iter_converter(tuple, int)
converter(["1", "2"])
>>> (1, 2)
```

I want to add type annotations to the `make_iter_converter` function properly, but I’m not sure how to do it correctly. Here is my attempt:

```py
_ITEMS_T = TypeVar("_ITEMS_T")
_ITEM_T = TypeVar("_ITEM_T")

def make_iter_converter(
    items_converter: Callable[[Iterator], _ITEMS_T],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], _ITEM_T],
) -> Callable:
    def wrapped(items: Iterator) -> _ITEMS_T[_ITEM_T]:
        return items_converter(item_converter(item) for item in items)

    return wrapped
```

However, this raises an error when I try to use `_ITEMS_T[_ITEM_T]` as the return type of the wrapped function:

```
TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable
```

I learned that *TypeVar* objects cannot be used with square brackets like some other types. Is there a way to fix this error and annotate the function properly? I know that *Generic* classes can accept type arguments, but that would require defining a separate class, and I don’t think that’s a good solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since we unfortunately do not have [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548) in Python yet (as mentioned by @SUTerliakov in a comment), there is currently no way to express the concept of a type variable bounded by a type that is itself parameterized by (i.e. generic in terms of) another type. So something to the effect of `I[T] = TypeVar("I[T]", bound=Iterable[T])` is not possible.

For your use case that would have been ideal of course.

For the time being, the best workaround I can think of is to provide as many signature overloads as you like to cover the most common use cases and have a catch-all overload for the rest. Something like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
AnyIter = Iterable[Any]


@overload
def make_iter_converter(
    iter_converter: Callable[[AnyIter], set[Any]],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], T],
) -> Callable[[AnyIter], set[T]]: ...


@overload
def make_iter_converter(
    iter_converter: Callable[[AnyIter], list[Any]],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], T],
) -> Callable[[AnyIter], list[T]]: ...


@overload
def make_iter_converter(
    iter_converter: Callable[[AnyIter], tuple[Any, ...]],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], T],
) -> Callable[[AnyIter], tuple[T, ...]]: ...


@overload
def make_iter_converter(
    iter_converter: Callable[[AnyIter], AnyIter],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], T],
) -> Callable[[AnyIter], Iterable[T]]: ...


def make_iter_converter(
    iter_converter: Callable[[AnyIter], AnyIter],
    item_converter: Callable[[Any], Any],
) -> Callable[[AnyIter], AnyIter]:
    def wrapped(items: AnyIter) -> AnyIter:
        return iter_converter(item_converter(item) for item in items)
    return wrapped
```

Demo: (for Mypy)

```py
tup_int_conv = make_iter_converter(tuple, int)
set_str_conv = make_iter_converter(set, str)
frozenset_bool_conv = make_iter_converter(frozenset, bool)
reveal_type(tup_int_conv)
reveal_type(set_str_conv)
reveal_type(frozenset_bool_conv)
```

Mypy output:

```
Revealed type is "def (typing.Iterable[Any]) -> builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]"
Revealed type is "def (typing.Iterable[Any]) -> builtins.set[builtins.str]"
Revealed type is "def (typing.Iterable[Any]) -> typing.Iterable[builtins.bool]"
```

Notice that the converter to the `frozenset` is inferred as returning simply an iterable of `bool` items, because there was no specific overload for it. The item type is the only type argument that is fully generic here.

This is obviously not ideal and far from elegant, but it is at least still halfway generic and if you know the most common applications, you can easily extend this.

Answer (score -1):

This one works, *pylance* is able to tell the output type based on the input.

```py
_ITEMS_T = TypeVar("_ITEMS_T")
_ITEM_T = TypeVar("_ITEM_T")

def make_iter_converter(
    items_converter: Type[_ITEMS_T],
    item_converter: Type[_ITEM_T],
) -> Callable[[Iterator], Type[_ITEMS_T][_ITEM_T]]:
    def wrapped(items: Iterator) -> Type[_ITEMS_T][_ITEM_T]:
        return items_converter(item_converter(item) for item in items)

    return wrapped
```

Comment: While this may work for you under some forgiving setup (maybe pylance just does some black magic which is not supported by Python standard), this is not a correct soultion, because higher-kinded type vars do not exist in python. Here's a corresponding [fr on python-typing[(https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548). `mypy` correctly rejects this snippet. (downvote mine)